# Get virtual host config without config file

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4

I've accidentially deleted a virtual hosts file `010-foo.conf`. The Apache2.4 is still running without `reload` or `restart` so far. Is there a way to see actual config of the file which isn't there any more (maybe via apachectl command or whatever)?

Comment: It's easiest to restore your backup.

Comment: This file was written and deleted before backup :( - but sure, you're right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have mod_info installed, you can use `gcore` to dump the parent Apache process (the one owned by pid 1) memory to a file, then search it for "VirtualHost" or something. I just tested it on my system and it works. You'll have to mess around with something like `grep` to cut out what you want and replace the config file.

```
gcore <pid>
less core.<pid>
```

**EDIT (from OP):**

If you don't have `gcore`, you can install it via `apt-get install gdb` (Ubuntu). The pid file is typically located under `/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid`. Then you can do the commands mentioned above and search the binary files, e.g. with `grep -obUaP "text to search" <dump file>`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17168777/2648551) for more information about using grep for binary files.

Comment: Oh, ok. I fixed the problem, already. But I tried a test with your solution and it gives me a huge dump file with the wanted information in it. I will edit your very helpful answer. Thanks a lot for pointing that out. It will surely help other people with the same problem. It could be time-consuming getting all the information, but they are present there! That's really good.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed `mod_info`, you can [use that to print your server configuration](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_info.html). In my case, I can see the entire configuration as Apache sees it, including all VirtualHosts.

If you don't have `mod_info` installed and working already, this information may not be available to you.

You can also see some VirtualHost information on the commandline by using [httpd -S](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/httpd.html). It's not complete, but it's better then nothing:

> ```
> -S
> Show the settings as parsed from the config file (currently only shows the virtualhost settings).
> ```

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful. But it seems that not all information are sent. There was also a path to a wsgi file which I can't see in the output of `apachectl -S` command (ok, you mentioned it).

Comment: You would think that a program running in memory would be able to show you it's configuration as it currently stands.

Comment: Oh, I have to correct myself: it seems that apachectl -S looks at the file in sites-enabled (which links to sites-available). Yes, something like this. Showing program's config out of memory or from temporary written file or whatever. I know the chances aren't good for that.

Comment: Technically, `apachectl` first checks in the global system configuration files (On RHEL, this would normally be `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`). From there, it should receive the correct `ServerRoot` setting. On my setting, `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` says `OPTIONS='-d /etc/httpd'`, and therefore httpd is called as `httpd -d /etc/httpd`. `/etc/httpd` would need to include the sites-enabled directory somewhere.

Comment: Thanks again. The server isn't RHEL, it's an latest LTS Ubuntu based LVS. So the paths are [different](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout#Debian.2C_Ubuntu_.28Apache_httpd_2.x.29:). But no chance as well to get the content of the deleted file with any of these information. It seems that the information/content of `010-foo.conf` is gone and not accessible outside of the file. Do you agree?

Comment: I agree. If you don't have mod_info installed already, you probably cannot retrieve the configuration for that one VirtualHost.

Comment: Yes, no `mod_info` installed or active under _mods-enabled_. But `apache2ctl -l` gives me `mod_log_config.c`. This sounds promising. But no idea if it could be relevant here. If you edit your answer with mod_info info, I can accept it. A 'not possible without mod_info' is also an answer :) Thanks for a lot of good comments.

Comment: Thanks @StefanLasiewski - your answer gives me good information about how Apache works and was helpful. But what really solves my problem (getting the information via a dump) was given in another answer.